# Applying inverse Mellin transform to get Riemann explicit formula

Tags: complex-analysis, mellin-transform

The $\psi(x)$ is the second Chebyshev function.

The $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Mellin inversion theorem:

$$\varphi(s)=\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}\,dx$$
$$f(x)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\varphi(s) x^{-s}\,ds$$

Starting with:
$$\tag{1}-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta (s)} \frac{1}{s}=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\psi (x)}{x^{s+1}} \, dx$$
Using substitutution $s=-z$:
$$\tag{2}-\frac{\zeta'(-z)}{\zeta (-z)} \frac{1}{-z}=\int_0^{\infty } \psi (x) x^{z-1} \, dx$$
Applying inverse Mellin transform:
$$\tag{3}\psi(x)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\left(-\frac{\zeta'(-z)}{\zeta (-z)} \frac{1}{-z}\right) x^{-z}\,dz$$
Reversing substitution $z=-s$ and $\frac{dz}{ds}=-1$:
$$\tag{4}\psi(x)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\left(-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta (s)} \frac{1}{s}\right) x^{s}\,(-1) ds$$
This simplifies to:
$$\tag{5}\psi(x)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta (s)} \frac{x^{s}}{s}\,ds$$

> But the correct formula should be:
>   $$\tag{6}\psi(x)=-\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta (s)} \frac{x^{s}}{s}\,ds$$

**I cannot spot a mistake. Can you tell me where I went wrong?**

Comment: I'm working from a "not-so-smart" phone, so apology if I'm not seeing this correctly.  It appears the sign error occurs in going from $(3)$ to $(4)$.

Comment: @Mark Viola I also thought this step is most likely the source of error, but I looked at it many times and see nothing wrong with it. Maybe I am blind.

Comment: @Mark Viola I got it! I forgot to change integration limits in $(4)$... :-D

Comment: Pleased I could help!

Comment: $\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta (s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda(n) n^{-s} =s \int_1^\infty (\sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n)) x^{-s-1}dx$. And you should work first on the Riemann explicit formula for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda(n) e^{-nx}$ ie. for $\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta (s)} \Gamma(s)$ because except the poles, it is fast decreasing on vertical strips.

Comment: @reuns Can you explain in more details what you mean?

Comment: @reuns That I should "work first on the..."

Comment: The Riemann explicit formula is obtained from the residue theorem applied to 
 $$\psi(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{2-iT_n}^{2+iT_n}+\int_{2+iT_n}^{-\infty+iT_n}+\int_{-\infty-iT_n}^{2-iT_n}\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta (s)} \frac{x^s}{s}ds$$ The main difficulty is to find a sequence $T_n \to \infty$ such that $\int_{2+iT_n}^{-\infty+iT_n}\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta (s)} \frac{x^s}{s}ds \to 0$ (which needs a careful analysis of the vertical density of non-trivial zeros).

Comment: You should try first with $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \Lambda(m)e^{-mx}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{2-iT_n}^{2+iT_n}+\int_{2+iT_n}^{-\infty+iT_n}+\int_{-\infty-iT_n}^{2-iT_n}\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta (s)} \Gamma(s)x^sds$ which is much easier because $\Gamma(s)$ is fast decreasing on vertical strips.

Comment: @reuns So, there is some sequence for which this particular integral does not go to zero?

Comment: No but that's what you need to prove in order to show $\sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}$ converges (for $x > 1$, when grouping $\rho$ with $\overline{\rho}$)

Comment: @reuns Ahhh... thank you